# How do you call functions integrable over any compact subset of their domain?

Tags: lebesgue-integral

I'm quite sure there is a name for such class of functions but can not remember or figure out what terms to search for. A simple and very practical example would be "periodic Lebesgue" functions: functions which are periodic—and thus, except for null cases, can not in principle have a Lebesgue integral over $\mathbb{R}$–but are integrable in their restriction to the fundamental interval. Or any finite interval whatsoever, for that matter.

Comment: [Locally integrable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_integrable_function).

Comment: @T.Bongers: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks for the push! If it's worth an answer to you, I could accept it. Otherwise, I guess I'll delete the question for being too trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such a function is called [locally integrable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_integrable_function), and the space of such functions is generally notated as $L^1_{\text{loc}}$ for this reason. An alternative, and equivalent, definition, is that for all infinitely differentiable $\varphi$ with compact support, we have

$$\int |f \varphi| dx < \infty$$